# Set the column value from page item by using JavaScript (Oracle APEX interactive grid)

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm working with APEX 20.1 interactive grids and I'm using the following code to get the value from the item "P7_DATE" into the column 'ADDING_DATE'.

```
var widget = apex.region('myIG').widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
model.forEach(function(r) {  
    model.setValue(r,"ADDING_DATE",apex.item("P7_DATE").getValue());
});
```

I have two issues:

1. This code only works for the first row;
2. I have another column called 'code' and I need to add a condition that (if 'code' is not null then run the code above).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1. Already tested, and the code you provided works just fine (please check the interactive grid, page item, and column IDs);
2. Regarding your second question, to only run the script when 'code' is not null, you only have to add an if condition with the current 'code' row value:

   ```
   var widget = apex.region('myIG').widget();
   var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
   var model = grid.model;
   model.forEach(function(r) {
       if (model.getValue(r,"CODE") != '') {
           model.setValue(r,"CODE",apex.item("P7_DATE").getValue());
       }
   });
   ```